# Recieving audio stream with Gstreamer results in reason not negotiated error

Tags: audio, gstreamer, multicast, gstreamer-1.0

I would like to stream audio data from MIC with Gstreamer.
However I could not play MIC audio with rx.
How can I play audio stream from MIC input?

> tx: gst-launch-1.0 -v alsasrc device="hw:0" ! decodebin ! audioconvert
>   ! rtpL16pay ! queue ! udpsink host=239.0.0.1 auto-multicast=true
>   port=5004
>
> rx: gst-launch-1.0 udpsrc multicast-group=239.0.0.1 port=5004
>   caps="application/x-rtp" ! rtpL16depay ! alsasink
>
> rx result: Setting pipeline to PAUSED ... Pipeline is live and does
>   not need PREROLL ... Setting pipeline to PLAYING ... New clock:
>   GstSystemClock ERROR: from element
>   /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstUDPSrc:udpsrc0: Internal data flow error.
>   Additional debug info:
>   ../../../../gstreamer-1.8.1/libs/gst/base/gstbasesrc.c(2948):
>   gst_base_src_loop (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstUDPSrc:udpsrc0:
>   streaming task paused, reason not-negotiated (-4) Execution ended
>   after 0:00:00.009364000 Setting pipeline to PAUSED ... Setting
>   pipeline to READY ... Setting pipeline to NULL ... Freeing pipeline
>   ...

tx result is as follows.

> Setting pipeline to PAUSED ... Pipeline is live and does not need
>   PREROLL ... Setting pipeline to PLAYING ... New clock:
>   GstAudioSrcClock /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstAlsaSrc:alsasrc0:
>   actual-buffer-time = 200000
>   /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstAlsaSrc:alsasrc0: actual-latency-time =
>   10000 /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstAlsaSrc:alsasrc0.GstPad:src: caps =
>   "audio/x-raw\,\ format\=(string)S16LE\,\
>   layout\=(string)interleaved\,\ rate\=(int)44100\,\
>   channels\=(int)2\,\ channel-mask\=(bitmask)0x0000000000000003"
>   /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstDecodeBin:decodebin0.GstGhostPad:sink.GstProxyPad:proxypad0:
>   caps = "audio/x-raw\,\ format\=(string)S16LE\,\
>   layout\=(string)interleaved\,\ rate\=(int)44100\,\
>   channels\=(int)2\,\ channel-mask\=(bitmask)0x0000000000000003"
>   /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstDecodeBin:decodebin0/GstTypeFindElement:typefind.GstPad:src:
>   caps = "audio/x-raw\,\ format\=(string)S16LE\,\
>   layout\=(string)interleaved\,\ rate\=(int)44100\,\
>   channels\=(int)2\,\ channel-mask\=(bitmask)0x0000000000000003"
>   Redistribute latency...
>   /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstAudioConvert:audioconvert0.GstPad:src: caps
>   = "audio/x-raw\,\ layout\=(string)interleaved\,\ rate\=(int)44100\,\ format\=(string)S16BE\,\ channels\=(int)2\,\
>   channel-mask\=(bitmask)0x0000000000000003"
>   /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstRtpL16Pay:rtpl16pay0.GstPad:src: caps =
>   "application/x-rtp\,\ media\=(string)audio\,\
>   clock-rate\=(int)44100\,\ encoding-name\=(string)L16\,\
>   encoding-params\=(string)2\,\ channels\=(int)2\,\
>   payload\=(int)96\,\ ssrc\=(uint)3961155089\,\
>   timestamp-offset\=(uint)725507323\,\ seqnum-offset\=(uint)20783"
>   /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstQueue:queue0.GstPad:src: caps =
>   "application/x-rtp\,\ media\=(string)audio\,\
>   clock-rate\=(int)44100\,\ encoding-name\=(string)L16\,\
>   encoding-params\=(string)2\,\ channels\=(int)2\,\
>   payload\=(int)96\,\ ssrc\=(uint)3961155089\,\
>   timestamp-offset\=(uint)725507323\,\ seqnum-offset\=(uint)20783"
>   /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstUDPSink:udpsink0.GstPad:sink: caps =
>   "application/x-rtp\,\ media\=(string)audio\,\
>   clock-rate\=(int)44100\,\ encoding-name\=(string)L16\,\
>   encoding-params\=(string)2\,\ channels\=(int)2\,\
>   payload\=(int)96\,\ ssrc\=(uint)3961155089\,\
>   timestamp-offset\=(uint)725507323\,\ seqnum-offset\=(uint)20783"
>   /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstQueue:queue0.GstPad:sink: caps =
>   "application/x-rtp\,\ media\=(string)audio\,\
>   clock-rate\=(int)44100\,\ encoding-name\=(string)L16\,\
>   encoding-params\=(string)2\,\ channels\=(int)2\,\
>   payload\=(int)96\,\ ssrc\=(uint)3961155089\,\
>   timestamp-offset\=(uint)725507323\,\ seqnum-offset\=(uint)20783"
>   /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstRtpL16Pay:rtpl16pay0.GstPad:sink: caps =
>   "audio/x-raw\,\ layout\=(string)interleaved\,\ rate\=(int)44100\,\
>   format\=(string)S16BE\,\ channels\=(int)2\,\
>   channel-mask\=(bitmask)0x0000000000000003"
>   /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstAudioConvert:audioconvert0.GstPad:sink: caps
>   = "audio/x-raw\,\ format\=(string)S16LE\,\ layout\=(string)interleaved\,\ rate\=(int)44100\,\
>   channels\=(int)2\,\ channel-mask\=(bitmask)0x0000000000000003"
>   /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstDecodeBin:decodebin0.GstDecodePad:src_0.GstProxyPad:proxypad1:
>   caps = "audio/x-raw\,\ format\=(string)S16LE\,\
>   layout\=(string)interleaved\,\ rate\=(int)44100\,\
>   channels\=(int)2\,\ channel-mask\=(bitmask)0x0000000000000003"
>   /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstDecodeBin:decodebin0/GstTypeFindElement:typefind.GstPad:sink:
>   caps = "audio/x-raw\,\ format\=(string)S16LE\,\
>   layout\=(string)interleaved\,\ rate\=(int)44100\,\
>   channels\=(int)2\,\ channel-mask\=(bitmask)0x0000000000000003"
>   /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstDecodeBin:decodebin0.GstGhostPad:sink: caps
>   = "audio/x-raw\,\ format\=(string)S16LE\,\ layout\=(string)interleaved\,\ rate\=(int)44100\,\
>   channels\=(int)2\,\ channel-mask\=(bitmask)0x0000000000000003"
>   /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstRtpL16Pay:rtpl16pay0: timestamp = 725507323
>   /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstRtpL16Pay:rtpl16pay0: seqnum = 20783

I think rx pipeline is wrong, but I could not find the solution.
Please tell me how to make pipeline.

PS:
I tried following command, and rx play the mic audio! This means the reciever device is not able to play L16 audio?

> tx: gst-launch-1.0 -v alsasrc device="hw:0" ! decodebin ! audioconvert
>   ! audioresample ! alawenc ! rtppcmapay ! queue ! udpsink
>   host=239.0.0.1 auto-multicast=true port=5004
>
> rx: gst-launch-1.0 udpsrc multicast-group=239.0.0.1 port=5004
>   caps="application/x-rtp, media=(string)audio, clock-rate=(int)8000,
>   encoding-name=(string)PCMA, encoding-params=(string)2,
>   channels=(int)1, payload=(int)8" ! rtppcmadepay ! alawdec ! alsasink

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the caps in receive, try the following pipeline:

> gst-launch-1.0 udpsrc multicast-group=239.0.0.1 port=5004
>   caps='application/x-rtp, media=(string)audio, clock-rate=(int)44100,
>   encoding-name=(string)L16, encoding-params=(string)2, channels=(int)2,
>   payload=(int)96' ! rtpL16depay ! audioconvert ! alsasink

Comment: Thank you for replying. Actually I tried the same command, but the result is not changed from my question.... Do you know why?

Comment: could you try following pipeline to see if you are really getting some data (If you are receiving it should print data on terminal )?
gst-launch-1.0 udpsrc multicast-group=239.0.0.1 port=5004 caps='application/x-rtp, media=(string)audio, clock-rate=(int)44100, encoding-name=(string)L16, encoding-params=(string)2, channels=(int)2, payload=(int)96' ! rtpL16depay ! fakesink dump=true

Comment: yes, I got dump data. The result is as follows.

Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
Pipeline is live and does not need PREROLL ...
Setting pipeline to PLAYING ...
New clock: GstSystemClock
00000000 (0x756170e8): 01 8c 00 05 01 36 00 03 01 2d 00 04 01 52 00 07  .....6...-...R..
00000010 (0x756170f8): 00 f4 00 03 01 16 00 0c 00 f7 00 03 00 d0 00 05  ................

Comment: could you try printing output of command "pacmd list-sources"  if it does print out devices, then use pulsesink instead of alsasink

Comment: The command says "No PulseAudio daemon running, or not running as session daemon." Actually I do not want to use PulseAudio because CPU of the reciever device is poor. Are there any way to make rx play L16 audio with alsasink?

Comment: Okie.. could you try this pipeline on your Rx machine "gst-launch-1.0 -v -m audiotestsrc ! audioconvert ! audioresample ! autoaudiosink " and see if you can hear audio ? and then change to autoaudiosink instead of alsasink.

Comment: Rx could play mic audio if I use PCMA codec. Please see my question's PS. This means the device has no cpu power or memory to do this?

Comment: Sorry, I overlooked your reply. I tried audiotestsrc command, and I could hear audio with both autoaudiosink and alsasink.

Comment: Try this pipeline: gst-launch-1.0 udpsrc multicast-group=239.0.0.1 port=5004 caps='application/x-rtp, media=(string)audio, clock-rate=(int)44100, encoding-name=(string)L16, encoding-params=(string)2, channels=(int)2, payload=(int)96' ! rtpL16depay ! audioconvert ! alsasink

Comment: Thank you! Finally rx plays mic audio!! However there is a problem. Rx only plays Right channel ( When playing PCMA, it plays both L/R channels). Would you understand why this happens?